# How can I use WindowBuilder to add checkbox in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, windowbuilder

I have a `JTable` populated from database. My need is to add a column in the table  with a checkbox for each row. User should be able to select any number of rows by checking the check boxes. Also a checkbox should be present on the column header to select All rows.

How can I do this with Eclipse WindowBuilder?

Comment: *"How can I do this with Eclipse WindowBuilder?"* Well, how you'd do it in **Java** is to ensure the table column is identified as containing Boolean values. For details see [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: *"Also a .."* Concentrate on one question per thread, please. SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk. Keeping it 'one question per thread' also makes it easier to find later. If people were looking for information on how to add a checbox in a table **header**, they would be less likely to follow a link titled *"How can I use WindowBuilder to add checkbox in **JTable**?"* ..